# AngularJS + ExpressJS + mongoose: Add delete functionality

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I am pretty new to AngularJS, and even newer to ExpressJS and Mongoose.  I have been following a tutorial to post to, and get from my database, but I'm having trouble adding delete functionality.

Here is where I call my delete function:

```
<ul ng-repeat="disease in diseases">
    <li>
        {{ disease.name }}: {{ disease.chipped }}, 
                            {{ disease.received }}, 
                            {{ disease.smashed }}, 
                            {{ disease.complete }}
    </li>
    <button ng-click="removeDisease(disease)"></button>
</ul>
```

... and in my controller I have:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'TrelloApi',
    'diseases',
    function($scope, TrelloApi, diseases){

        $scope.diseases = diseases.diseases;

        $scope.removeDisease = function(disease) {
            console.log(disease);
            diseases.destroy(disease);
        }
    }
]);
```

...which calls my `diseases` factory:

```
app.factory('diseases', [
    '$http',
    function($http){

        var o = {
            diseases: []
        };

        o.destroy = function(disease) {
            return $http.delete('/diseases/' + disease._id).success(function(data){
                console.log("Disease " + disease.name + " has been removed!");
                o.getAll();
            });
        };

        return o;
    }
]);
```

This returns with a 404 error: 
`DELETE http://localhost:4000/diseases/<id> 404 (Not Found)` even though in my my routes include:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Disease = mongoose.model('Disease');

// Not functional
router.delete('/diseases/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req);
});

// Functional
router.post('/diseases', function(req, res, next) {
  var disease = new Disease(req.body);

  disease.save(function(err, diseases){
    if(err){ return next(err); }

    res.json(diseases);
  });
});
```

... and `ui.router` includes:

```
app.config([
    'TrelloApiProvider', 
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function(TrelloApiProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        .state('diseases', {
            url: '/diseases/{id}',
            templateUrl: '/javascripts/home/_diseases.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');   
    }
]);
```

There is also a template found at `/javascripts/home/_diseases.html`.  I have a feeling I am missing one piece but I just can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you start Express HTTP server:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.delete('/diseases/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  const id = req.params.id;
  console.log(id);
});

const app = express();

app.use('/', router);

const server = http.createServer(app).listen(8080, serverCallback);

function serverCallback() {
  const host = server.address().address;
  const port = server.address().port;
  console.log(`Server listening on ${host}:${port}`);
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error, only now its `DELETE http://localhost:4000/api/diseases/569edff5b829031c5ebcc75f 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: still no luck... I receive the same `404`.  Could it have something to do with not finding the template rather than something being wrong with the url?

Comment: have you actually started the http express server or this is all code you have in Node.js?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101215/discussion-between-jeremy-thomas-and-kyrylkov).

Comment: the answer or from the chat?